# Laravel custom login losses Session after redirect

Tags: laravel

i need a two way Login. First check database one if user exists and if not check database two.
So i build a custom Login Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class CustomLoginController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
    if($request->email) {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('/');
        } else {
            DB::setDefaultConnection('otherdb');

            if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
                // The Login credentials will be found and user will be logged in 
but after Redirect to home user isn't logged in anymore.
                return redirect()->intended('/');
            } else {
                return redirect()->to('/login')
                    ->withInput($request->only($credentials['email'], 'remember'))
                    ->withErrors([
                        'email' => Lang::get('auth.failed'),
                    ]);
            }
        }
    } else {
        return view('auth.login');
    }
    }
}
```

After i changed the database Connection with "DB::setDefaultConnection('otherdb');", the second login works but after Redirect to any page user isn't logged in anymore.
What am I doing wrong?
Any ideas?

Comment: Were is your session stored?

Comment: Sessions where stored in files.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel trying to find a user in DB in every request. So after redirect there in no user **in your default database**. DB connection doesn't stored in session.

I think you need to create a custom auth guard with another user model like

```
class OtherUser extends Eloquent 
{
    protected $connection = 'otherdb';
}
```

and work with it.

Comment: Ok, i don't know this "Laravel trying to find a user in DB in every request". I will try to build a custom guard. Thanks